# Tails 1.0 Frugal install: How to?

Tags: grub2

I work on Ubuntu 13.10 and I'd like to "frugal install" Tails 1.0.
Is there anybody who knows how to edit 40_custom file to do it?
I found the following:

```
menuentry "Tails" {
    set isofile="/boot/iso/tails-i386-1.0.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,7)$isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live config noswap nopersistent
iso-scan/filename=$isofile nomodeset
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

after that, I update grub and restart my Pc; System found Tails, but doens't start.
Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this entry in `40_custom` instead:

```
menuentry "Tails Security" {
loopback loop (hd0,7)/boot/ISO/tails-i386-1.3.2.iso
linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live union=aufs noswap noprompt ip=frommedia findiso=/boot/ISO/tails-i386-1.3.2.iso toram=filesystem.squashfs
initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I've reformatted and expanded this slightly, but I still recommend you [edit] this answer to explain (a) what this does--specifically, what it does differently, and (b) why this works (or why you think it is worth attempting).